# Which of these two JS lines costs less?

Tags: javascript, performance

Assume that booleanMatrix[x][y][z] is true 10% of the time. Which of the alternatives are more efficient?

```
if (booleanMatrix[x][y][z]) booleanMatrix[x][y][z] = false; // alternative 1
booleanMatrix[x][y][z] = false; // alternative 2
```

The two alternatives give the same functionality [edit] in the context of my program [/edit]. Alternative 1 first checks the value before possible rewriting it. Alternative 2 just goes straight ahead and writes it. So, i suppose this boils down to whether the cost of accessing the value of a variable is smaller than the cost of editing it. Is it?

EDIT: Elsewhere in my program, an undefined booleanMatrix[x][y][z] is treated as if it were false. This is why alternative 1 does not give ill consequences in my program.

Comment: "`The two alternatives give the same functionality.`" No, they are not. In case `booleanMatrix[x][y][z]` is not defined or is `0`, `null`, `NaN` or `''`, the first-one will not override it, the latter will.

Comment: You are right. I updated my question to clarify what I meant.

Comment: The answer to this question is implementation specific. What holds true now may not be true next year, or the year before. It's best to spend 10 minutes to write a benchmark and get the answer yourself.

Comment: @Teemu or `undefined`. Always forget one!

Comment: The real question is if not checking it doesn't affect your program then why would you check it at all ever anyway?  You may as well add some lines like `var s = 0 + 'abc'` since those don't affect your program either.

Comment: @Teemu actually no, those are slightly different - `delete obj.x` is not the same as `obj.x = undefined`

Comment: @djechlin That's correct, but the condition in `if` can't see the difference?

Comment: Everyone's input is highly appreciated, I've learned from it. Unrelated to the issue, I'm puzzled about two upvotes disagreeing with 3 downvotes for my Question. Why is it that the community is split on the quality of my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really slick benchmarking tools out there that are great for things like this. Specifically, I would recommend jsperf. Here is a test I wrote up for this scenario: http://jsperf.com/read-or-write.

After running this test, the conclusion is that writing without testing is, in general, *MORE EFFICIENT* option.

**NOTE**: Some of my test results conflict with those from Renato (http://jsperf.com/testing-before-vs-just-writing). The reason for this likely relates to his test using a different ratio of trues and falses. Or maybe to his test using a single-dimension array while my test uses three-dimensional arrays.

So, you should notice that this result is NOT very reliable. It seems that there are many other factors that are actually more significant than the specific question you are asking. These results might vary a great deal with arrays of different dimensions, with arrays of different ratios of true and false, with different browsers, etc.

It seems that ultimately, the performance difference is not especially significant. However, you could always write additional tests that are more specific to your scenario in order to get some more definitive results.

Comment: Actually, if you update Renato's test to use the correct ratio of true to false values (see http://jsperf.com/testing-before-vs-just-writing/2) then it agrees with yours, so that was probably the issue.  Note that the graph on that page is showing exactly the same number for both, which is not the results I saw when I ran it - something seems to have gone wrong in the graphing.

Comment: Excellent answer. I was not aware that such useful tools existed, I will play around with it a bit to be certain that alternative 1 is indeed most efficient. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, a one-dimensional array would just make the results less pronounced than a three-dimensional array. I still believe this answer to be incorrect.

Comment: @AlexW Why do you think it is incorrect? In your answer below, you claim that alt 2 is more efficient because it doesn't run an if statement. Are you taking into consideration that the condition is true only 10% of the time?

Comment: @user3324865 It isn't incorrect now because, if you look at the edit history, he changed his answer from LESS EFFICIENT to MORE EFFICIENT.

Comment: Yes, I switched my result. I found after running my tests on different browsers, I obtained very different results. So I then edited my answer to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

Writing without testing before seems to be faster: http://jsperf.com/testing-before-vs-just-writing

Answer (score 0):

Alternative 2 is of course more efficient,

Break those two alteratives in 2 different operations:

```
if (booleanMatrix[x][y][z])
```

and

```
booleanMatrix[x][y][z] = false;
```

The first alternative is operation 1 + operation 2, and the second alternative is operation 2, therefore, alternative 2 will always be faster, the question is, does it work for what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative 1 will always take *slightly* more time to execute because it has to run through the logic of the `if()`. The *only* cases where these would be equal are:

- if the `if()` statment took no time to evaluate.
- or  if the JavaScript engine optimized alternative 1 to be equal to alternative 2